# Compare dates in table where similar columns are in different rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL Server 2008/12 question. I'll try to give a simplified explanation.

With a table of data

- 1st col contains ids, 5 chars,
- 2nd col contains codes, 1 char (always = 1 or 2)
- 3rd col contains dates in YYYYmmdd format

Like this:

```
create table #temp 
(
     id varchar (5),
     code varchar (3),
     dt varchar(8)
)

insert into #temp (id,code,dt)
values ('abc00', '2', '20180101'), ('abc01', '1', '20180201'),
       ('def00', '1', '20180201'), ('def01', '2', '20180101'),
       ('ghi00', '2', '20180101'), ('ghi01', '1', '20180102'),
       ('jkl00', '1', '20180101')
```

I need one or more select queries that do the following:

For the entire table, if the 1st 3 chars of id are equal they're "related" ids (`left(id, 3)` is the same)

So for each "set" of related ids find `min(id)` and `max(id)`, then make sure that `min(id).date < max(id).date`

I've tried answers involving `OVER(PARTITION id)`, CTEs self joins and temp tables, but I can't get my head around how to put it all together to make it work.

I seem to get stuck where I'm looking for the different lines of related ids.

I'm working on comparing the dates for each related id, find out which one is greater. If i can get that working I think I can bring it home.

I got some help from another thread ([Compare dates between 2 different rows and columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28588008/compare-dates-between-2-different-rows-and-columns)), but the added complexity of limiting the search between the the current row and all "related" ids is stumping me, and that's where I think I'm bombing out.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
select * 
from #temp 
where cast(dt as date) > (select top 1 cast(dt as date) 
                          from #temp AS sub
                          where sub.id in (select id 
                                           from #temp 
                                           where (left(#temp.id, 3) = left(sub.id, 3)) 
                                             and (#temp.id <> sub.id)) 
                          order by id)
```

... but that's returning no rows. I've been banging my head on this all day.

**Edit**:

As an example of what I'm expecting here:

Using this stmt:

```
select * 
from #temp sub 
where 'abc' = left(sub.id, 3) and ('abc01' <> sub.id)
```

I get this result:

```
id    code dt
----- ---- --------
abc00 2    20170101
```

Thanks for the edit tip @Philip

Can anyone help?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Tables has `Columns` **NOT** `Fields`

Comment: Can you include a mock up of what you would expect the results to look like?

Comment: Off-topic: according to your description you should think about re-design the table structure. Maybe you should split the column id into 2 columns: one with the first 3 char which is string, and the second with the int value. This will probably allow you to improve performance a lot

Comment: The first issue I see here is that you are storing dates as strings. Why so many people do this is beyond me. We have date and datetime datatypes for a reason. Use them. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type

Comment: Don't **ever** store `Date` as `String`, use the `Date/DateTime` datatypes.

Comment: existing struct, i have no control. i use cast(as date) when comparing in that table.

Comment: @dave, you can update your original question... so please put your example/results data there!

Comment: @PhilipKelley thanks! updated!

Comment: @Sami the data comes in from a govt source mainframe (i completely changed everything except the structure). i can't change the datatype, and we need to store it as is, because we have to pass it back eventually for processing on a mainframe. i prefer date and datetime and always use them in my own stuff, when i can.

Comment: Thank you all guys! Cheers. Ahmed got the answer below. I was so close and got code blinded. Remember! data and datetime are friends!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i think you want this ?

```
select * from #temp 
        where cast(dt as date) > 
            (select TOP 1 cast(dt as date) from #temp AS sub
                where (left(sub.id,3)) in 
                ( 
                    select (left(id,3)) AS Id from #temp where (left(#temp.id,3) = left(sub.id,3))  AND #temp.id  != sub.id 
                ) 
            )
```

Comment: oh ffs! lmao! you win the internets today.  That's exactly it. I can't believe i was that close. I was putting off posting this for hours, and just writing it all out got me 95% of the way. Thank you so much! Cheers! Dave

Comment: wish i could upvote you. i'm still a newb and don't have enough karma. but i did give you credit for the answer! thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
select
    grp = left(id, 3),
    MinDt = min(dt),
    MaxDt = max(dt)
from #temp
group by left(id, 3)
having min(dt) < max(dt)
```

Comment: you must convert the string to dates if you want to compare them (there is no meaning for min(dt) < max(dt) when these are strings and you want min/max according to the date value)

Comment: I'm not tackling the questions he didn't ask. Enough comments were attached to the OP to drive that point home.

Comment: Also, it *looks* like the date data is in YYYYMMDD format, so the min/max comparisons should be valid. Assuming the data is valid and consistent, of course.

Comment: Thanks. I edited the OP to show what i'm expecting back, for each row. If this were another language i could debug it to see what #temp.id and sub.id hold during that inner select, but can't do that in mssql, of course.